# RStudio, cantidad de días ingresando año y meses

Tags: r, script, rstudio, año-bisiesto

Ingresar como datos de entrada un año y el número de mes(enero=1, febrero=2,...). Se deberá devolver el número de días que tiene o tendrá ese mes en el año determinado.

Comment: Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.

Comment: Bienvenido  a Stack Overflow en español, te sugiero que hagas el [tour] y de paso ganes tu primer medalla, también es muy importante que leas [ask] para poder mejorar tu pregunta y que sea bien recibida por la comunidad mejorando así, tus chances de obtener buenas respuestas.